# BAT - cannot send emails

Tags: email, webserver, domain, smtp, email-client

**THE SITUATION:**

I am using [BAT software](https://www.ritlabs.com/en/products/thebat/) to send and receive emails.

Everything was working fine, until i moved two days ago to Turkey (in Italy and Latvia everything was working as expected).
Since then i was not able anymore to send emails anymore.

But i can still receive emails.

**THE SETTINGS:**

Right now i am using the following settings:

**Send email:**

SMTP Server 
mail.MY_EMAIL_DOMAIN.lv 
Connection: regular 
Port: 25

**Receive email:**

mail.MY_EMAIL_DOMAIN.lv 
Protocol: Pop3 
Connection: regular 
Port: 110

**THE ATTEMPTS:**

I search around similar issues and find out that maybe is the provider that can block some ports.

But i have tried to send email with port 25, 587, 465 and with none of them was working.

These are the messages appearing in the log:

```
 SEND  - Connecting to SMTP server mail.MY_EMAIL_DOMAIN.lv on port 25
 SEND  - Could not connect to the server. A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond
```

**THE QUESTION:**

Why i cannot send email? Is related with the ports being blocked? 
Do you know how can i resolve this issue?

Thank you very much!

Comment: You say you cannot send, but can you receive email okay?

Comment: Exactly. I can receive but cannot send.

Answer (score 1):

Your provider or a firewall is blocking the smtp traffic. Try finding the smtp relay server your provider in Turkey provides. If "mail.MY_EMAIL_DOMAIN.lv" supports authenticated mail most providers should also allow you to use this through the submission port 587.

Comment: +1.  Contact your ISP to see what SMTP server they require you to use.  Some ISPs do this so all mail can be routed through their servers in order to block spam from egressing their networks.